# PHP - How to exclude a character while using explode() function?

Tags: php, explode

```
<?php
$value = 'SKU,Title,LIST PRICE,SELL PRICE,STORE ID,Image,Points,Stock,Product Category,Pricing Attributes "S-030-2324","Salwar Test4",12,10,3,,10,14,"salwar_kameez"';

$val = explode(',',$value);
```

I want to exclude the exploding if (comma)',' is present inside (double quotes)""

Comment: have you tried to do anything with this so far? Are you saying you want to exclude the values that are quoted? Or you want to ignore commas within strings that are quoted?

Comment: This is beyond str_explode.  Use CSV functions.

Comment: Well you can't do that with a simple string replace.  You'll need to use a regular expression match or use @PaulDixon's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing sounds closer to CSV, so [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) might be a better fit for your problem.

```
$text='one,two,"three,four"';
$cols=str_getcsv($text);
print_r($cols);
```

Produces this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three,four
)
```